# storing struct as value using CFDictionarySetValue()

Tags: c++, c, core-foundation

Iam new to using Core Foundations. I want to use dictionary to store some key value pair. The value must be a pointer to a struct. This pointer is pointing to dynamically allocated buffer.

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef init_hash_table() {

    return CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
}
```

This is used to create the dictionary and the return value is stored as global variable.

```
CFNumberRef
create_hash_key(int sd) {
    return CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &sd);
}


int
add_hash_entry(CFMutableDictionaryRef dict, int sd, void *pkt) {

    CFNumberRef key = create_hash_key(sd);

    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, key, pkt);
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this code, I get segfault. I see that pkt has a valid address and key seems to be created. Does anyone know how to assign a pointer to value part?

> Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
>   Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000011
>   0x00007fff8c9f339f in objc_msgSend_fixup ()

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use Cocoa instead of Core Foundation? It could save some headache.

Comment: Nothing as such, I just started using CF and my use of it is pretty limited. This is the only usecase.

Comment: CF is needed sometimes. To quote Apple: **Important:** Use a CFDictionaryRef data type rather than an NSDictionary object to track touches, because NSDictionary copies its keys. The UITouch class does not adopt the NSCopying protocol, which is required for object copying.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks` argument. From the documentation:

> `kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks`
>   Predefined `CFDictionaryValueCallBacks` structure containing a set of
>   callbacks appropriate for use when the values in a `CFDictionary` are
>   all `CFType`-derived objects.

So in your case, `CFRetain()` is called on the pointer when the value is added to the
dictionary. This causes the crash because the pointer does not point to a CoreFoundation
object.

You can create the dictionary with

```
CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, NULL);
```

instead, so that no "reference counting" will be done on the value.

Alternatively, you can wrap the pointer into a `CFDataRef` and put that into the
dictionary.

In both cases it is your responsibility that the pointer is still valid 
when the value is retrieved from the dictionary later.

---

Here is a *simple* example how you could implement refcounting for your custom objects:

```
typedef struct {
    int refcount;
    int val;
} mystruct;

const void *myretain(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value)
{
    mystruct *p = (mystruct *)value;
    p->refcount++;
    return p;
}

void myrelease(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *value)
{
    mystruct *p = (mystruct *)value;
    if (p->refcount == 1)
        free(p);
    else
        p->refcount--;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    mystruct *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->refcount = 1;
    p->val = 13;

    CFDictionaryValueCallBacks vcb = { 0 , myretain, myrelease, NULL, NULL };
    CFMutableDictionaryRef dict =  CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &vcb);

    int sd = 13;
    CFNumberRef key = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &sd);

    CFDictionarySetValue(dict, key, p);
    // refcount == 2
    myrelease(NULL, p);
    // refcount == 1

    mystruct *q = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, key);
    // refcount is still 1, "GetValue" does not increment the refcount

    CFRelease(dict);
    // object is deallocated

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin R, for narrowing it down. But your answer looks like an easy way out, shifting the problem somewhere else instead of solving it. Would a custom DictionaryValueCallBack keep reference counting active, and can you give an example that works?

Comment: Or can I shove my struct elements into a CFArray and use kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBack, after all?

Comment: @PeterKämpf: The question was about a pointer that *"is pointing to dynamically allocated buffer"*, so I assumed that there is no refcounting available. Of course, if the pointer points to something that implements refcounting (such as, for example, a COM interface) then you could provide the corresponding value callbacks. So "an example that works" depends on what kind of pointer you want to store. - Putting the pointer into CFArray first just moves the problem because that also uses a CFArrayCallBacks parameter.

Comment: @PeterKämpf: I have added a very simple example of a custom value callback with a custom refcounting.